# Calling PythonFunction's from a VB application hosting Iron Python

Tags: vb.net, scripting, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime, hosted

I'm a C++ programming who was tapped to write a small application in Visual Basic.  The application hosts an IronPython runtime and I am attempting to define some function in python and then call them from VB. I have written a simple test function in python

```
def test(): 
    print "Test was Called"
```

Then I use the iron python to create a ScriptSource from the python file.  I am able to look up the "test" variable through object operations but I can not figure out how to call the object that.  For example (in VB):

```
pyScope = engine.CreateScope()
pySource = engine.CreateSourceFromFile("C:\Some\File\path\test.py")
pySource.Execute(pyScope)
' Now I expect the function test() to be defined in pyScope
Dim tmp as Object
pyScope.TryGetVariable("test", tmp)
```

At this point in my code tmp is defined as an object of type PythonFunction.  I can't figure out how to call this function.

```
tmp()
```

Is not valid VB syntax.  I've gotten this far, now how do I perform this seemingly simple task?

Edit: By calling

```
 pyEngine.Operations.Invoke(tmp)
```

I am able to call the function and I see the expected output at stdout.  I am still under the impression that there is some function-pointer-like type that I can cast objects of type PythonFunction to which will let me invoke temp directly without calling to the Python engine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work, but try casting it to an Action type:

```
DirectCast(tmp, Action)()
```

---

Based on the comment, try this:

```
engine.ObjectOperations.Invoke(tmp, Nothing)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  I get an exception of "Unable to cast object of type 'IronPython.Runtime.PythonFunction' to type 'System.Action'."

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere - I have a type I can work with. Updating.

Comment: Ha, I just discovered that right before I commented on your post.  From reading the documentation and looking at C# examples I feel like I should be able to cast tmp to a callable type.  See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dark-corners.shtml#delegates-and-calltarget0

Answer (score 0):

VB in .NET 4 should have the same dynamic support as C#.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx#Y5108 (near the bottom), you should be able to do:

```
Dim tmp As Object = scope.GetVariable("test")
```

... which is what you're already doing, so make sure you're targeting .NET 4.

If that doesn't work you should be able to cast it with the generic version of `GetVariable`:

```
Dim tmp As Action = scope.GetVariable(Of Action)("test")
```

Finally, you already discovered `Invoke` on ObjectOperations.

(You may need to tweak the syntax, since I don't know VB.)